# Axis2 webservice exposing - listSingleService not found exception

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, apache-axis, tomcat6

I'm trying to expose a WS using Axis2 on already existing webapp
So I setup what I had to setup : axis2-conf.xml, modules I'm using, services.xml is loaded correctly, also the Axis2 runtime for my Tomcat..
When I try to test my WS using the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/services/TestService?wsdl
```

I get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Le fichier &quot;/axis2-web/listSingleService.jsp&quot; n'a pas été trouvé
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractAgent.renderView(AbstractAgent.java:120)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:309)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:254)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Saying that the JSP **listSingleService.jsp** was not found...
Anybody faced this problem before? thanks in advance!

Comment: There are too many reasons this coul be happening

Comment: I mentioned my configuration, do you see anything weird? do you need any more information?